# How to warm-up Twig?

Tags: 8, caching, theming

I would like to warm-up Twig templates after cache rebuild or when needed. By warming-up I mean to process each twig template into php file.

Is this possible without rendering the content first?

Comment: Ok, let's stop the edit nonsense here. "warm-up" is a technical term applied to cache, there is no reason to remove it from the question, title or otherwise. This question is both clear and answerable in its original form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can warm up the twig cache with drush:

```
twig-compile (twigc)  Compile all Twig template(s).
```

The twig cache is located in

```
/sites/default/files/php/twig
```

Here you can check the compiled php files.

Answer (score 2):

The question sounds like coming from a Drupal 7 background :)

If I understand it correctly, you are looking for a way to execute some PHP logic before rendering the content. Just like what we were used to do in the `*.tpl.php` files.

However, PHPTemplate was removed and replaced by Twig for a reason. **For truly separating business and presentation layers** - on of the major reason.

This does not mean that you loose on to the control which you had with PHPTemplate files. This only means that you are now forced to follow the best standard practices ;-)

Ideally, in both Drupal 7 and 8 the template functions the rendering should be broken in two steps:

1. Business logic - The function which is responsible for initializing the data (to be returned to page). This could be a function which calls the `theme()` function, like the `page callback` of your `hook_menu` implementation where you pass the variables into it. These could also be the `preprocess` functions which could be used to add new and or change existing `$variables` to the theme element being called.
2. Presentation logic - These are nothing but the functions or template file responsible for printing the values that it gets from the Business layer into appropriate markup. In D7 we used `*.tpl.php`, whereas in D8 we use `*.twig`.

To deal with the issue at hand, you will need to the [template_preprocess()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/8) function. The `*.twig` file is responsible to **only print the variables**, with minimum logical checks.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the misunderstanding. I have rolled back the question to what I have originally wrote before some **** changed it to something completely different. Feel free to update or remove your question.

Comment: @IvanJaros This is a community site, so it is expected to show respect towards people trying to help! The person who edited the question might be at mistake. No one is perfect. If someone is wrong, you have to point it out respectfully. That is how as a community we grow.

Comment: And as per the edited question, the answer still stands unchanged. preprocess is the way to get it done.